# R関連：gs_readで日本語のテーブルを読み込むと文字化けする

Tags: r

Rのgs_readを使い、Google Spreadsheetにある日本語を含むデータを読み込もうとしていますが、文字化けになってしまします（文字化け例：不動産→`<U+5186> <U+4E0D><U+52D5><U+7523>`）。以下のコードを使っていますが、どなたか解決する方法をご存知ないでしょうか？

```
library(googlesheets)
gs_ls()
data <- gs_key("シートのキーがここにはいる")
data <- gs_read(data)
```

Answer (score 3):

googlesheetsパッケージの`gs_read`関数ではreadrパッケージのテキストファイル読み込み用の引数がオプションとして利用可能です。

エンコードを指定するlocaleという引数に以下のような指定をしてみてはいかがでしょうか。エンコードの値はお使いのOSに応じて切り替えてください。

```
library(readr)
# windows 
gs_read(data, locale = locale(encoding = "cp932"))
# unix 系
gs_read(data, locale = locale(encoding = "UTF-8"))
```